# how do i insert a directive into a view from angular controller?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I have a custom directive in my angular module that I would like to dynamically insert into my view with multiple instances containing different information from a function inside the controller also in the module.. how is this done? For examples sake [here is a sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/HB7LU/) to use to show me how this is done

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E", 
        transclude: true,
        template: "<div><h4>Hello, World!</h4></div>"
    }
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.insertDir = function(){
        //????
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you think about your Angular app (and in general when you "think in MVVM"), imagine the controller changing some state of the app - which is the ViewModel or `$scope` in Angular - and try not to think in view-specific terms when you design your controller.

Then, when you're building the view, try to make the view react to the app's state (i.e. `$scope`).

Keep this separation and your life will be easier.

Specifically to your question. Create values that would "drive" your view (however the view wants). If your view wants to create directives based on this value (or array of values) so be it. It could do so like this:

Suppose your controller sets `$scope.values`, like so:

```
.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.values = ["AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD"];
})
```

then your view could do something like:

```
Hello, {{name}}!
<my-directive ng-repeat="v in values">{{v}}</my-directive>
```

If you want to "add directives", again, think about adding values into your $scope.values, not directives to the view. For example, you could do so in a function in your controller that reacts to a user's click:

```
$scope.addNewValue = function(){
   $scope.values.push("New Val: " + Math.random());
};
```

Here's your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/6930/).

Comment: @AlexScott, not sure why you unmarked this as the answer. `ng-repeat` is just one way the View decides how to render. It can just as easily use `ng-if="values[N] !== undefined"` and sprinkle the directives wherever you want.

Comment: yeah i didnt mean to - apologies

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng-if`. I.e. `<div ng-if="myDirectiveActive"> <my-directive></my-directive> </div>`. It will insert the `div` with your directive into the DOM tree whenever `myDirectiveActive` flag is true

Comment: im wanting to add multiple of these directives containing unique data loaded from the controller. i dont really understand your solution

Comment: `ng-if` inserts containing elements into the DOM whenever the expression served to it is true. It's almost like `ng-show`, but instead of just hiding the element, it INSERTS it into the DOM tree  (and removes it, if the expression evaluated to false). 

So, if you want to insert your directive into the DOM, just put it inside an element with `ng-if="isMyDirectiveActive"` on it, and then just change `$scope.isMyDirectiveActive` to to true whever you need to activate the directive. On the next render cycle, your directive will be inserted into the DOM and activated. Is this more clear?

Comment: yes i understand however this doesnt give me the functionality that i want. I am wanting to add these directives in from a function call, so I dont have to explicitly state how many directives are going to be present in the view. With your method I would need to insert <mydirective></duirective> inside the ng-if div for each directive I am planning to put in there... but i dont know how many I will need, they need to be dynamically inserted

Answer (score -2):

Try this, use `$compile` service to compile your directive with a given scope.

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $compile,$document) {
  $scope.insertDir = function(){
    var x = $compile('<my-directive></my-directive>')($scope);
    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = x[0].innerHTML;
  };
});
```

Comment: Why?? This is so wrong - don't modify the view from the controller